# Can Maven profiles be defined in different files?

Tags: maven

Ive got a Maven project ive inherited which has no profiles setup, however I need to set different different profiles for dev/int/staging etc.

From what ive read I can put in profile elements into the main POM but there are alot of dependency configuration elements so this file would become huge, so I was wondering if there was a way of telling the main POM to reference different files, so it would be something like:

- POM.xml
- DevProfile.xml
- IntProfile.xml
- StaProfile.xml

Im assuming its not possible and I just have to deal with a huge POM, but thought I would ask in case it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) can be placed either inside the POM, or outside in [Settings](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html). You're much better off keeping machine specific settings outside of the POM (as you note), but you can't include dependencies (as far as I know) in settings.

I've had to include things like native libraries as dependencies and have successfully used profiles, but did have to use the POM. (NOTE though, this is one of the only reasons I can think of to need to include deps in a profile, generally you shouldn't, and if possible you'll want to avoid it because those parts of the build become non-deterministic.)

To cut down on the size of the POM you can use inheritance. You can make separate POMs for each machine that use a common parent that has all the common stuff in it. Be careful though, inheritance can affect the way profiles are activated. Use the [Help](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/plugin-info.html) plugin to see the "effective POM" (and or effective-settings) to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Will give you the answer, it appears that I cannot do what I was wanting to do, but its not the end of the world. Thanks for answering!